# Is there an IDE that can simplify the process of creating a game matchmaking website?

Tags: software-engineering, matchmaking

Yes, I'm an old guy. And I'm well versed in "C" and have written several games which I have been selling on the web for a number of years. And now, I would like to adapt one of my games to be "online". Sounds simple. I'm sure I can use the thousands of lines of "C" code that I've already written. Right?

So my initial investigation begins. First, I think I'll need a server program that lives on a dedicated server (or a VPS probably) that talks to a bunch of client applications that live on individual devices around the world. I can certainly handle that! (I think to myself). I'll break up my existing game into two pieces, a client piece that is just the game displays and buttons, and a server piece that does everything else. Piece of cake, right?

But that means that the "server piece" must be executed on a remote machine somewhere and run 24/7. Can I do that? [apparently, that question is so basic, so uneducated, and so lame, that nobody has ever posed it before. Because hours of Googling does not yield an answer. Fine. I'll assume I can do that and move on.]

I'll need a "game room", which to me means a website where you log in and then go to a lobby of some kind where you can setup your preferences, see if any of your friends are connected, and create or join games. Should be easy, but it's not. No way. Can I do all this with my local website builder? (which happens to be 90 Second Website Builder, a nice product, btw). It turns out, I can not. I can start with that, but must modify each page, so I can interact with my sql database. So I begin making each page a "PHP" page and dynamically modifying the HTML code with PHP code.

I'm already starting to get a headache.

Because the resulting web pages looked terrible, I began looking at using JQuery. I want to user a JQuery dialog on my website to display a list of friends and allow the user to select one to invite to the game. [google search for "how to populate a JQuery dialog from a sql database" yields nothing but more confusion.]

Javascript? Java? HTML? XML? HTML5? PHP? JQuery? Flash? Sockets? Forms? CSS? Learning about each one of these, and how they interact with each other and/or depend on each other is too much for my feeble old brain.

Can anyone simplify this process for me? Is there an IDE that will help me do all this without having to go back to college for a few years?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Probably off topic for this site. Unless you're talking about modifying your game to be online, and not just making a matchmaking website. I think the IDE you're looking for is the job boards over at gamedev.net.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that there would be a benefit to using wildly different technologies for the match/chat stuff as for the game.  I, personally, would only use HTML/JS for the game room if I were planning on implementing the game in it as well.  I don't have experience with this, though, so this isn't an answer.

Comment: Oops, sorry Sean, I just noticed that I overwrote your edit.

Comment: It seems to be a law of web development that you can't get anything done without using about 8 different languages.  Start simple, and don't worry about making pages look pretty at first, as that drags in a whole other can of worms.  Get a good book - [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Web-Database-Applications-MySQL-Edition/dp/0596005431/) is decent and should get you going.